# Use unique id to deserialize object via json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Spring JPA POJO:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

}
```

Without going into details, it is easy via Spring MVC to deserialize the following JSON to Employee object instance

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}
```

**My questios**: since each employee has a **unique id**, is it possible to only send only the employee id via JSON, and somehow via Spring JPA, and Jackson magic to retrieve the rest of the information

```
{
  "id": 1
}
```

The function that would deserialize JSON to object would be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/update") 
public void updateFilter(@RequestBody Employee emp) { 
employeerepo.save(emp); 
}
```

Technically, I can write a function to do the mapping and such, but I have a feeling that someone else had this problem before and there is clean and elegant way to do it without much coding

Comment: Do  you want to read employee by passing `{"id": 1}`?

Comment: @SagarRohankar Rohankar. Yes!